# Objective C singleton class members

Tags: objective-c, macos, singleton

This is for a Mac OS X app. I have created a singleton class, but I'm not sure how to add class members (not sure if this is the correct term). I am getting the error `Property 'chordDictionary' not found on object of type '__strong id'` and I'm not sure why. I want to create an NSDictionary that I can access via this class. Here's my code:

```
#import "ChordType.h"

@interface ChordType()

@property NSDictionary *chordDictionary;

@end

@implementation ChordType

+ (instancetype)sharedChordData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedInstance.chordDictionary = @{@"" : @"047", @"m" : @"037", @"dim" : @"036", @"aug" : @"048",}; //error is on this line
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `sharedInstance` as `ChordType *` instead of `id` or call the `setChordDictionary:` method instead of using the property syntax. You can't use property syntax on variables of type `id`.

Either:

```
static ChordType *sharedInstance = nil;
```

or:

```
[sharedInstance setChordDictionary:@{@"" : @"047", @"m" : @"037", @"dim" : @"036", @"aug" : @"048"}];
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your header file of ChordType class

```
@property NSDictionary *chordDictionary;
    + (ChordType *)sharedChordData;
```

and then modify your code with this

```
+ (ChordType *)sharedChordData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedInstance.chordDictionary = @{@"" : @"047", @"m" : @"037", @"dim" : @"036", @"aug" : @"048",}; //error is on this line
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Then you can access properties like this,

```
[ChordType sharedChordData].chordDictionary = @{@"" : @"047", @"m" : @"037", @"dim" : @"036", @"aug" : @"048"};
```

In this way your accessing **chordDictionary** as public property through its sharedInstance that is **shareChordData** sharedChordData is basically a static method that can be accessed via class member.

Comment: 1) What changes did you make to the `sharedChordData` method? It looks the same as the OP's. 2) The OP doesn't seem to want the `chordDictionary` property to be public and doing so has nothing at all to do with the issue.

Comment: From the question i have not seen any thing that he dont mentioned that he dont need property as public

Comment: The question is about a specific error. Nothing in your answer addresses the error. The scope of the property has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Why you are fighting , its open to share anwers , i had just given another option that desired solution can be achieved in this way also. chill man

Comment: I'm not fighting. I'm simply pointing out that your answer makes no attempt to solve the problem asked in the question. Answers are expected to actually answer the question being asked. Please explain how your answer solves the error posted in the question. Also please explain  what modification you are referring to in the `sharedChordData` in your answer. Your method appears to be identical to the `sharedChordData` method in the original question.

Comment: I have change return type of this function "sharedChordData" and in question user has asked to access and modify dictionary via class instance, but i have not access dictionary via class instance , i had access dictionary see last highlighted part of my anwer ... please